# Long gt table pdf output breaks at the end of the page

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

I'm trying to generate a summary table which is quite long in a **pdf format**.
But the table is breaking down at the end of the page (See the image below). I guess it is something to do with page margin.

[image]

I have checked the online documentation. It has argument **page.margin.bottom** in **tab_options()** to work with a **RTF** format. Is there any workaround for pdf format.
The following example closely mimics my problem. But table is not breaking at the end. However, it is very close to the page margin.

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
d = iris %>% gt() 
d
gtsave(d, filename = "long_table.pdf", zoom = 0.7)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution using RMarkdown that converts it into a PDF. Knit (Cntrl+Shift+K) the Rmd file in RStudio to create the pdf file in your working directory.

Normally, RMarkdown uses 3 backticks (e.g. ```{r codechunk}) to create and end a code chunk. Since stackoverflow also uses 3 backticks to create a codeblock, I will swap out the Rmd codechunk 3 backticks for *** instead.

Output screenshot: https://prnt.sc/vhO5Px59mWYQ

```
---
title: "test_pdf"
output: pdf_document
---

***{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
tinytex::install_tinytex() #install this if you have not already
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
***

***{r iris2, echo=F}
dfA <- iris 
dfB <- iris
df <- bind_rows(dfA, dfB)
d <- df %>% gt()
d
 
***
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Unfortunately, I want it to be done using gt or any convenient package.

Comment: tip: Rmarkdown flavoured code/text can be code-fenced with four backticks, e.g. ```` so that you don't need to replace the back-ticks with *.